# ASP.NET MVC Configurable Validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, config

I would like to use the asp.net mvc client / server validation coming from a configurable source.

Some like a .config file where I could place infos:
Type, Member, ValidationType

```
<validations>
    <add type="Customer" member="Name" validator="Required" />
    <add type="Customer" member="Age" validator="Range" mimimum="18" maximum="100" />
</validations>
```

With this plan, would be possible to enable/disable validations.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need this, consider some more advanced validation framework, for example Enterprise Library Validation Block.

If you want to do it yourself, i would suggest creating custom attribute iniherited from ValidationAttribute like this (partly pseudocode, i am sure you get the idea)

```
public class ConfigurableValidationAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
       string objectType = value.GetType().FullName;
       string objectName = GetMyObjectName(value); // interface? reflection?
       var validationRules = GetValidationRulesFor(objectType, name); // from your configuration

       foreach (var rule in validationRules)
       {       
           ValidationAttribute attr = null;          
           switch (rule.ValidatorName)
           {
              case "Required": attr = new RequiredAttribute();
              case "StringLength": attr = // you get the idea
           }

           if (!attr.IsValid(value)) return false;
       }

       return true;
    }
}
```